# Properly display day number from a string array of days

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

A user input day of Monday should come back with a "1" while an integer input of "1" should to come back with the day "Monday". Right now a zero is representative of Monday. My understanding was that I needed to add 1 to it, hence the +1 as seen below, but that has only complicated things more. 
Any input is appreciated.

```
string[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void BtnGetNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dayName = (txtDayName.Text);
    int dayIndex, dayNumber;
    dayIndex = Array.IndexOf(days, dayName);
    lblNumOut.Text = dayIndex.ToString();
}

private void BtnGetDay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int dayNumber;
    if (int.TryParse(txtDayNum.Text, out dayNumber) == false || dayNumber < 1 || dayNumber > 7)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Must be a valid number from 1 to 7.");

    }
    lblNameOut.Text = (days[dayNumber + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
private void BtnGetNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dayName = txtDayName.Text;
    int dayIndex;
    //To find the index of the day ignoring the case, so the input can be monday, Monday, mOnDaY...etc.
    dayIndex = Array.FindIndex(days, a => a.Equals(dayName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    //Check if the input is a valid day name:
    if(dayIndex == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter correct day name.");
        return;
    }
    lblNumOut.Text = (dayIndex + 1).ToString();
}

private void BtnGetDay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int dayNumber;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtDayNum.Text, out dayNumber) || dayNumber < 1 || dayNumber > 7)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Must be a valid number from 1 to 7.");
        return;
    }
    //0-based index. When the input say = 3, that means the value position in the array is 3 - 1 = 2.
    lblNameOut.Text = days[dayNumber - 1];
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Appreciate the fast response. It didn't change the functioning of the form however as it still displays 0 for Monday.

Comment: @wavers00 I think now it works as per your need. The `BtnGetNum` should return dayIndex + 1.

Comment: JQSOFT Appreciate the help.